# Angular/Ionic ng-if

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue with an Ionic app we are building.

On a particular screen, the app is going to list one or more names, using an ng-repeat directive in a div. The div will also feature a select element. Based on the value of the select element, I would like another sub-div to display or hide. This is what I have so far:

```
<ion-list>
    <div class="item item-input item-select" ng-repeat="customer in data.customerList">
        <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-balanced" style="border:none;" ng-click="onCheckboxClick($event, customer.SubjectId)"></ion-checkbox>
        <div class="input-label item-text-wrap">{{customer.CustomerName}}</div>
        <select ng-model="customer.ServiceType" ng-options="o as o for o in data.serviceTypes" ng-disabled="customer.Served == false"></select>
        <div ng-if="customer.ServiceType == 'Non Personal'">
            <p>Div Stuff to Display Here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

And here is how the data retrieved from the controller:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.customerList = {};
$scope.data.serviceTypes = ['', 'Personal', 'Non-Personal'];

$http.get(ApiEndpoint.url + '/GetJobDetails?id=' + $scope.jobId).then(function(resp) {
    for (i = 0; i < resp.data.Customers.length; i++) {
        var newCustomer =
            {
                "CustomerName": resp.data.Customers[i].CustomerName,
                "SubjectId": resp.data.Customers[i].SubjectId,
                "Served": false,
                "ServiceType": ""
            };
        $scope.data.customerList[i] = newCustomer;
    }

}, function(err) {

});
```

What I'm trying to do is display the div:

```
<div ng-if="customer.ServiceType == 'Non Personal'">
<p>Div Stuff to Display Here</p>
</div>
```

when the select value equals 'Non Personal'. Currently nothing happens when the select value changes. I've tried swapping the ng-if to a ng-show and the same result occurred.

Is anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="customer.ServiceType" ng-options="o as o for o in data.serviceTypes" ng-disabled="customer.Served == false" value="{{o}}"></select>
```

You need to set the value to `{{o}}`

Alternatively, you can also use `track by`

```
<select ng-model="customer.ServiceType" ng-options="o as o for o in data.serviceTypes track by o" ng-disabled="customer.Served == false"></select>
```